# Geolocation: Add user location Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, geolocation, google-geocoder

I would have user location on my map with stores around him (store model).
I used [Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation) but I'm lost... 
Actually, I have my map with stores, and the map move to the user location but doesn't show the infoWindow "Location found".

Here is my map.js :

```
    import GMaps from 'gmaps/gmaps.js';
import { autocomplete } from '../components/autocomplete';

const mapElement = document.getElementById('map');
if (mapElement) { // don't try to build a map if there's no div#map to inject in
  const map = new GMaps({ el: '#map', lat: 0, lng: 0 });
  const markers = JSON.parse(mapElement.dataset.markers);
  map.addMarkers(markers);

  if (markers.length === 0) {
    map.setZoom(2);
  } else if (markers.length === 1) {
    map.setCenter(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng);
    map.setZoom(14);
  } else {
    map.fitLatLngBounds(markers);
  }


  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var pos = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      };

      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({map: map});

      infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
      infoWindow.setContent('Location found.');
      map.setCenter(pos);
    }, function() {
      handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
    });
  } else {
    // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
    handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
  }


  function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
    infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
    infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
                          'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
                          'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
  }

}
```

The controller :

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :authenticate_user!

  def home
    @store_all = Store.all
    @stores = Store.where.not(latitude: nil, longitude: nil)
    @markers = @stores.map do |store|
      {
        lat: store.latitude,
        lng: store.longitude,
        infoWindow: { content: '<a href="/stores/' + store.id.to_s + '">' + store.name + '</a><br/>' +
                               store.category +
                               '<br>' +
                               store.address
        }
      }
    end
  end
end
```

And the view:

```
<div class="wrapper-map text-center">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <div
            id="map"
            style="width: 100%;
            height: 600px;"
            data-markers="<%= @markers.to_json %>"
          ></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Thank you for your help, I try a lot of tutorials but lost, I am. :)

Comment: Can you create a reproducible issue on codepen/jsfiddle/other similar website? Would go a long way for helping us help you.

Comment: https://codepen.io/FrancoisRab/pen/bajPXE here it is but I can't add my controller to codepen unfortunately